# Mailchimp API and YII framework

Tags: yii, mailchimp, yii-extensions, yii-components

Has anyone used Mailchimp api with YII framework? Is there an well documented extension? I found an extension but it has no documentation https://github.com/jamesmoey/Yii-MailChimp.

Answer (score 3):

There is a well documented [php api](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php) from mailchimp, there is no need for a yii extension. Simply include the `MCAPI.class.php` and create a MCAPI object with your api key. You will have all functions available like `listSubscribe($id, $email_address)` etc.

**Edit**

The extension you refer to is a simple wrapper for the official wrapper. You will have the same methods available.